# How can I make this one function?

Tags: jquery

I know that I should be able to do this within one function. I have 2 buttons that show 2 different forms when clicked. When one is toggled the other will hide. Here is how I am doing it now.

```
$("#newaccount_form").hide();
$("#newuser_form").hide();

$(function(){
$("#newaccount").on("click", function(){
    if ($('#newuser_form').is(":visible"))
    {
        $("#newuser_form").hide("slow");
        $("#newaccount_form").slideToggle("slow");
    }
    else{
        $("#newaccount_form").slideToggle("slow");
    }
    });
});

$(function(){
$("#newuser").on("click", function(){
    if ($('#newaccount_form').is(":visible"))
    {
        $("#newaccount_form").hide("slow");
        $("#newuser_form").slideToggle("slow");
    }
    else{
        $("#newuser_form").slideToggle("slow");
    }
    });
});
```

How can I turn this into one function? How can I make 2 elements hit the same function?

Comment: you can use 'data' attribute to element . and using 1 class name to both element you can able to manage in single click event .  by getting 'data' attribute on button click you can put conditions to hide show forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can match ID of element clicked to the forms selectors

```
var $forms = $("#newaccount_form, #newuser_form").hide();

$("#newaccount, #newuser").on("click", function(){
    var target_form = $('#' + this.id + '_form').slideToggle();
    $forms.not(target_form).slideUp(); // or hide()    
});
```

It's not really necessary to check for `:visible` if you use specific animation instead of toggle.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gqrhm8bc/1)**</kbd>

Comment: This works however, I cannot hide both forms if the user chooses too. One has is constantly being displayed.

Comment: Can change the first animation to slideToggle then

Comment: yep, that works perfect, and it much neater then what I had working. Thanks!

Comment: please consider assigning the form id into an html data attribute of the button and then pick the target form id from this attribute not to have the hardcoded logic.`<button id="newaccount" data-target-form="#newaccount_form">`

Comment: @PavelGatnar no need when the relationship with id already exists

Comment: @charlietfl do you mean this? `$('#' + this.id + '_form')`

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that soon you will need to add more div's to show/hide. You should use a class as selector, and hide all div's (or any other element) before showing the one triggered by the button. When you have something like this:

```
<button class="toggle_btn" id="newaccount" data="newaccount_form">New Account</button>
<button class="toggle_btn" id="newuser" data="newuser_form">New User</button>

<div class="toggle red" id="newaccount_form"></div>
<div class="toggle blue" id="newuser_form"></div>
```

You can control it generically:

```
$(function(){
    $("#newaccount_form").hide();
    $("#newuser_form").hide();

    $(".toggle_btn").click(function() {
        $(".toggle").hide("slow");
        var dataSelectorId = $(this).attr("data");
        if ($('#' + dataSelectorId).is(":hidden")) {
            $("#" + dataSelectorId).slideToggle("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Try out on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jotamartins/mcrnkw87/1/)

Comment: This works for me as well, another great solution thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to use this method with drop down selections(on change) + buttons(on click) as the `toggle_controller` (instead of toggle_btn)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015716/jquery-show-only-a-single-div-at-a-time

Answer (score 0):

Using the jQuery.data() could solve this.
so,

```
$("#newaccount").click(function(){
    $(this).data('pressed', true);}
);
```

Then you can use an if statement to check for the arbitrary value. Then you can check it with an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#newaccount_form").hide();
$("#newuser_form").hide();

$(function(){
    $("#newaccount").on("click", show_new_form("#newaccount_form", "#newuser_form"));
    $("#newuser").on("click", show_new_form("#newuser_form", "#newaccount_form"));
    function show_new_form(new_form, current_form){
        return (function(){
            if ($(current_form).is(":visible"))
            {
                $(current_form).hide("slow");
            }
            $(new_form).slideToggle("slow");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not work at all, when I use it my forms are constantly being shown, and when the button is clicked nothing happens.

Comment: I just rewrote your piece of code. when you move the lines with hide into the $ function, it runs ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#newaccount_form").hide();
$("#newuser_form").hide();

$(function(){
$("#newaccount,#newuser").on("click", function(){
    if ($('#newuser_form').is(":visible"))
    {
        $("#newuser_form").hide("slow");
        $("#newaccount_form").slideToggle("slow");
    }
    else if ($('#newaccount_form').is(":visible"))
    {
         $("#newaccount_form").hide("slow");
         $("#newuser_form").slideToggle("slow");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_form").slideToggle("slow");
    }
    });
});
```